# How to check if an Id exists in within a field in a List<sObject>?

Tags: apex, lookup

I am trying to think of a good way to do this, but no luck yet. So: I will have two Lists: `List<Date__c>` and `List<Project__c>`. There is a look-up relationship between `Project__c` to `Date__c`, so `Project__c` has a field that holds the value of a `Date__c id`.

Goal: To find out whether there is a Project associated with a Date or not.

This should provide more clarity:

```
For all dates in List<Date__c>{
    If there is a Project for this date in List<Project__c>{
        get Date info, get Project info
    }
    else{
        get Date info, null
    }
}
```

I read about a lot of posts that refer to copying the List data into a Set or Map and use the 'contains' method, but one of my biggest problems is how to do something like `PREFERRED_COLLECTION<Project__c.Lookup_Date__c>.contains(Date__c.Id)`
where PREFERRED_COLLECTION could be a Map or a Set (because those support the contains method).

And what is the best way to go about this, especially when there are a lot of records to loop on? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of doing this, and each has it's pros and cons which depend on what you want to do with the information.

Given you already have the  2 lists, you'd probably use this approach.
Because a Date__c record can have many Project__c records you probably want to construct a Map of a Date__c Id to a set of Project__c Ids.
Assuming you have the following variables:

- `List<Date__c> dateList`
- `List<Project__c> projectList`

Your code could look like this:

```
// define a map variable that will map the Id of a Date__c to a set of Project__c records
Map<Id, Set<Id>> dateToProjectMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>> ();

// go through the Project__c records and find the ones that have one or more Date__c records
for(Project__c proj : projectList) {

    // if we haven't initialised the Set for this Date__c Id yet, let's do that
    if(!dateToProjectMap.contains(proj.Date__c)) {
        dateToProjectMap.put(proj.Date__c, new Set<Id>());
    }

    // now add the Project__c.Id to the map
    dateToProjectMap.get(proj.Date__c).put(proj.Id);
}
```

This would construct a Map of the Date__c records that have at least one Project__c records. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could then use the `contains()` method to work out if a Date__c record has any Project__c children.

```
dateToProjectMap.containsKey(dateIdWeWant);
```

---

Alternately, if you can change the query that retrieves these records, you can add the relationship within the query itself.  See also the [SOQL reference guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm)

You could do:

```
// get children within one query.  Obviosuly add in some WHERE clauses and any other fields you want
List<Date> dateList = [SELECT Id (SELECT Id, Date__c FROM Project__r) FROM Date__c];

// go through the result to get the child Project__c records
for(Date__c thisDate : dateList) {
    List<Project__c> proj = thisDate.getSObjects('Project__r');

    // handle the projects
    if(proj != null) {
        // we have at least one Project__c record.  Do whatever it is you want to do with it.
    }
}
```

It's hard to say what to do with the results.  It will vary depending what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I am confused. I have two lists and they are being populated via SOQL. Where is the reference to the Date__c object in your idea? I believe the looping needs to be on the Date__c object and then Date__c.Id needs to be compared with the lookup field in Project__c.  How do you suggest I do that? An unrelated question: your SOQL says SELECT Id FROM ... and is dumping into a Map<Id, Project__c> While it is obvious that Id maps to Id, would Project__c object be automatically populated despite not being a part of the SOQL?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your initial question. I've update the answer to what I think you're after.  It might also help to explain what you want to do with the results as this can sometimes drive how you want to store the information.